# Solorized theme's selection text color too similar with background in iterm2

Tags: shell, iterm2

I use solorized dark color them in iterm2, but the color of selection text too similar with the background, how can I change it ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find it under *Preferences | Profiles | -Select your profile- | Colors:*[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal 2.4 (326):

Open your Terminal preferences (*Terminal > Preferences...*) -> "*Settings*" tab -> "*Text*" section -> "*Selection*" color-chooser

[image: "Settings" dialog -> "Settings" tab -> "Text" section -> "Selection" color-chooser]